# How to Pass a variable from .map() to callback function

Tags: mongoose, callback, promise, field

I have a function to return all involved Employees into a project.
here is part of my code to return list of employees but after I get employee info I need to add extra field into object and after that return it.

```
`    var involvedEmployees = employeeItems.map(employeeItem => {
            return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

                employeeId = employeeItem.employeeId;
                whatDid = employeeItem.whatDid;                    
                role = employeeItem.role;

                employeeModel.findById(employeeId, function(err, findedEmployee){
                    findedEmployee = findedEmployee.toObject();   
                    findedEmployee["NewField"] = Variable; //this Variable need to come from .map function
                    resolve(findedEmployee);
                });
            });                                
        });
        var results = Promise.all(involvedEmployees);
        results.then(data => {
            res.json(data);
        });
`
```

please tell me how can I send whatDid and role varables to findById callback function to add into object before resolve the promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your variables *employeeId, whatDid,* and *role* are global variables. Given that the *findById* callbacks will be executed *after* the `map()` method has iterated all employees, these three variables will be set to the last employee's data by the time these *findById* callbacks are invoked.

You can solve this in several ways. One is to declare your three variables with `let`, so they become local to the block, and each *findById* callback will reference that specific set of variables.

But why not just reference the properties of the *employeeItem* variable *inside* the *findById* callback? That variable is local, so you'll have the same advantages. You can use `employeeItem.employeeId` in that callback without problem.

Not related to your question: you should not have to create a new promise with `new Promise`, since with the `exec` method you can get a promise from the *findById* query:

```
var involvedEmployees = employeeItems.map(employeeItem =>
    employeeModel.findById(employeeId, (err, foundEmployee) => {
        foundEmployee = foundEmployee.toObject();
        foundEmployee.employeeId = employeeItem.employeeId;
        foundEmployee.whatDid = employeeItem.whatDid;
        foundEmployee.role = employeeItem.role;
    }).exec() // make it a promise
);
var results = Promise.all(involvedEmployees);
results.then(data => {
    res.json(data);
});
```

Comment: it work for me, as you said I just need to define my variables with let :) .   thank you very much.